# Facing issue with calendar image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Juery Datepicker when user clicked on the image next to input textbox.

I tried with the below code snippet to show button image and not sure image is not loading.

```
<input id="timeFrom" type="text" class="form-control" name="timeFrom">
 timeFrom.datepicker({
                 showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "~/Content/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true 
        });
```

I have placed calendar image in the same path and in UI the calendar image is not showing

[image]

Can some one please let me know how to show calendar.j

Answer (score 0):

I think the path to your buttonImage is not good, check it.

```js
$('#timeFrom').datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "https://findicons.com/files/icons/99/office/128/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    max-width: 24px;
    max-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css " />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="timeFrom" type="text" class="form-control" name="timeFrom">
```

Comment: I am not sure why I am not bale to load only when I place the path in button image. If I am dragging it in cshtml its loading correctly. The image is present in Images folder. Please let me know if anything else is missing. Even i set the image properties to set output as always.

Comment: Validate my answer if u find it usefull plz

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see image with the change in url and I am able to see the image

```
 timeFrom.datepicker({
                 showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "../Content/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true 
        });
```